# ios how to force to quit app

Tags: ios

Any of you knows how can I quick my app. I'm trying quick my app when I app is detecting is in a bad state. Any of you knows knows how can I implement this?

I'll really appreciated all your help.

Comment: Please explain your question.

Comment: the application should resolve the "bad states" or conflicts, instead of quitting...

Comment: exit(0);      //maybe this?

Answer (score 3):

Throw an exception.  That should terminate your app pretty quickly.

Caveat:  Your program should not allow for a bad state.  Throw an exception in your debug build, but once you find a situation that causes it *FIX IT*.  This is a process that many developers are sadly not familiar with called "debugging."

Answer (score 0):

If you call `exit(0)` in the middle of your app, it will clos automatically. However, Apple might reject your app from the App Store because it will seem like your app has crashed instead of purposely quitting.